# How to keep ssh connection alive?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Sometims I need to keep ssh connection alive for hour or even more.

Mysql big dumps or big TAR archives, for example, may require persistent connection for a long period of time. But Iam keep getting broken pipe error.

System is MacOs Lion.

How I can keep connection alive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can do it, the best way is to install [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on the remote server, and run your long processes within screen.  If your ssh session drops out for any reason (including timeout or simply a lost connection) the processes you are running will continue, and you can reconnect to them once you re-establish connection.

If this is not an option, then create

```
~/.ssh/config
```

and enter the line

```
ServerAliveInterval 240
```

Change `240` to a number of seconds appropriate to send a keep-alive to maintain a session.

Comment: ServerAliveInterval is the solution.